# Raw and simple_form...neither is perfect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, draper

I have this in one of my models:

```
def rank_match_2
...
...
array = [start, finish, [words]]

results = field.insert(start, "<mark>") and field.insert(finish, "</mark>") 
...
end
```

Now I know I shouldn't be adding view logic in the model, but I am building a search app that has quite a bit of logic built into how the results are rendered. At this point I don't see how to get around including it in the model, so I that's what I am doing.

My problem is this:

On the view, I have this:

```
<%=raw @parse.rank_match_2 %>
```

This effectively handles the html "mark" tags inserted in the model logic and DOES highlight the correct text, but DOES NOT include line breaks etc.

However, this:

```
<%= simple_form(@parse.rank_match_2).html_safe %>
```

does not handle the 'mark' tags and therefore DOES NOT highlight the correct text, but DOES correctly format the line breaks as expected.

I want to do both: highlight the correct text by inserting the 'mark' tags into the model object (which seems to work with 'raw'), AND render correctly formatted html with line breaks etc.

Any idea what I am missing. I am trying Draper gem but I don't think it is suitable for exactly what I want.